# Getting an error while adding an app to Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have taken free trial subscription of Office 365 Enterprise E3 and added a site as a developer site. Then I added an app which is a SharePoint add-in and tried to publish it using Napa online. But while doing so it's giving me an error as below

[image: Error screen]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue since yesterday. Sometimes it works for a few hours, then it doesn't.

Other users report the same problem:

[SharePoint o365 - Add-In (SharePoint hosted): ErrorDetail: The content database on the server is temporarily unavailable](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192573/sharepoint-o365-add-in-sharepoint-hosted-errordetail-the-content-database)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249801/office-365-app-deployment-issues-the-request-could-not-be-completed-because-of

So it seems that Microsoft messed something up. Let's hope they can fix it quick.

Comment: So its not related to something I can do right? Because I am trying since yesterday but getting the same error everytime.

Comment: Since multiple people have the same issue at the same time it seems obvious that the problem is on Microsoft's end and that we will have to wait for them to restore the degraded service.